# Pandemic - Will the expansions really make a difference?

Tags: pandemic

Hi i just bought myself Pandemic and played for the first time last night. I have mixed thoughts about the game. I love the setting, and i think it looks fab, but there's definitely something lacking with the game which i can't quite put my finger on.

I've played it 3 times. We won on the intro game. We won on the normal game, we cured 3 of 4 diseases on the hardest game. I thought this was meant to be a hard game?

I read somewhere that the expansion packs are what make Pandemic, but as i find myself finishing off my Gumtree ad to sell the game, i can't help but wonder if i should be giving it another chance. I think my major problem with it is that it's a co-op game, and i really am not big with co-op games, i just wanted one in my collection.

Any advice on the expansions you prefer or your thoughts on the game would be welcomed.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: How many people are you playing the games with. The game difficulty is generally increased with more players.

Comment: The way the game is balanced, getting three diseases cured is often a lot easier than getting all four diseases cured. Hence a 3 out of 4 is usually not "nearly won".

Answer (score 7):

First make sure you are playing the game correctly. From [BoardGameGeek FAQ](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/30549/pandemic):

> Q: Our first game was easy! Are we doing something wrong?
>
> A: Probably. But the game is easier with fewer players and/or fewer Epidemics in
>   the deck. You may also visit this thread to see if you missed
>   something: [Common mistakes](http://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/300287/common-mistakes).

Also try the game with different number of players. A two-player game is different and apparently easier than a four-player game. There is also quite a big lucky factor involved depending on how the infections are distributed and how early the epidemic cards occur.

If you still find the game too easy but otherwise like it, consider buying On the Brink expansion. It adds variety to the game by providing a lot more roles. It can also make the game harder by offering new challenges.

If you don't like the game, you probably don't like it with the expansions either. For me the base version was fun on it's own and hard enough, as we failed to find cures for any deseases on the first game with the easiest difficulty level when playing with four people.

Comment: Many thanks for that, it would seem that we were playing the game correctly after reading the info at the links you posted above. I suppose we were just lucky :)